# Why this code not working on Vscode (Python code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I used this code in Vs code:

```py
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.gov.uk/search/news-and-communications"

reponse = requests.get(url)

page = reponse.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

class_name= "gem-c-document-list__item-link"

titres = soup.find_all("a", class_=class_name)

titres_textes=[]

for titre in titres:

    titres_textes.append(titre.string)
    
titres_textes
```

But when I try to run it with `Ctrl+Alt+N`
nothing happens ,why ?

```
python versions>3.10
extensions python on Vscode> Python ok,Django ok,Magic-python ok,code runner,python for vscode ok
pip> Latest versions currently installed
```

Comment: How do you know nothing happens? Perhaps you could add some `print()` statements to tell you which parts of the code are running and which are not.

Comment: OK i try now thanks for  your reply

Comment: I put : print(titres_textes)  . But Vscodes answer :[Running] python -u "c:\Users\*****\Documents\python\test.py"
[]

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.572 seconds

Comment: Try adding `print(url)`. Does this print your url out?

Comment: url = "https://www.gov.uk/search/news-and-communications"
print(url)[Running] python -u "c:\Users\Nourdine\Documents\python\test.py"
https://www.gov.uk/search/news-and-communications

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.531 seconds

Comment: There are no HTML elements with the class gem-c-document-list__item-link on that page. Perhaps you meant gem-c-document-list__item-title

Comment: It come from   python lessons from "OpenClassRoom" so i dunno i just follow the lessons.https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/7168871-apprenez-les-bases-du-langage-python/7296776-extrayez-et-transformez-des-donnees-avec-l-extraction-web just watch the first video at 2:50 min. But sorry im French so it's in French

Comment: Online classes may give correct information when they're created but, especially if they use real publicly accessible websites, the HTML layout can easily change rendering the lesson invalid

Comment: Oh i see thanks for your reply everybody,i should change Url..thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use print and maintain proper code readability.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.gov.uk/search/news-and-communications"

reponse = requests.get(url)
page = reponse.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

class_name= "gem-c-document-list__item-link"
titres = soup.find_all("a", class_=class_name)

titres_textes=[]
for titre in titres:
    titres_textes.append(titre.string)
print(titres_textes)
```

Try running your code from VS Code terminal. Go to the path first then type the command:
***python filename.py***

Comment: Can you give me more informations please ,because i think im already in the right path >c:\Users\Nourdine\Documents\python\test.py but when i tried to execute the code, i have this in the VSCode Terminal >C:\Users\******\Documents\python> & C:/Users/*******/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/*******/Documents/python/test.py

Answer (score 0):

Agree with `BrutusForcus`, It is just because the HTML page has been changed. You can change the value of `class_name` to something others, and remove the string after `titre` to make it work.

Such as this:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.gov.uk/search/news-and-communications"

reponse = requests.get(url)

page = reponse.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

class_name = "gem-c-document-list__item-metadata"

titres = soup.find_all("ul", class_=class_name)

titres_textes = []

for titre in titres:

    titres_textes.append(titre)

print(titres_textes)
```